# Google BigQuery per ID partitioning technique

Tags: google-bigquery

I have BigQuery table with time series finance data (price, volume and other stuff):

```
ts:TIMESTAMP,
asset_id:INTEGER,
metric1:INTEGER,
metric2:INTEGER,
...
metricN:FLOAT
```

`id` is an external ID in the Postgres database.

The most common and frequent query is filtering by `id`. For example:

```
SELECT ts, metric1, metric2 WHERE id = 12;
```

**Is there a good way to partition data by `timestamp` and `id` in the same time?**

---

I'm thinking to create per `id` tables (`gc_project_name.per_id_dataset.{asset_id}`) and query them for better price/performance.

What issues can cause this approach? We have ~5k ids, and 10-20k would be enough for years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for short term, you can create per id day-partitioned tables, and use [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) to perform query.

for long term, we will provide two level partitioning mechanism, please stay tuned!